# karma setup giving require is not defined

Tags: javascript, testing, karma-runner

I'm new at setting up karma and testing here, so I've been going through a bunch of examples out there to set my env up.
However, whenever I run `karma start`, it gives me this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at test/person-test.js:1
```

I think I probably didn't set up my `karma.conf.js` correctly, does anyone have any clue? This is what I have:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'browserify'],
    files: [
      'test/**/*.js'
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.js': ['browserify']
    },
    plugins: [
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-browserify'
      ],
    browserify: {
      debug: true,
      transform: [ 'brfs', 'browserify-shim' ]
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

I have file structure like this:

```
.
├── src
|   └── person.js
├── test
|   ├── person-test.js
├── karma.conf.js
└── package.json
```

Where my `person.js` file is like this:

```
class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  upperCaseName() {
    this.name = this.name.upperCaseName();
  }
}

module.exports = Person;
```

and (so far) my `person-test.js` is:

```
const Person = require('../src/person.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to transform your source code for the browser, replacing require calls with the actual module code. Take a look at these utilities:

http://browserify.org/ - it does exactly the transformation you need

https://webpack.github.io/ - a more complicated web packaging framework, with lots of other useful features.

updated:

Karma is a test runner that runs your tests in a browser. Whatever browser you setup doesn't know what the require function is.

To use jasmine with node try jasmine-node. https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node

Comment: What does it mean? What if this is just a small non-browser app? where do place the script tag with bundle.js?

Comment: browser does not understand the require statement , you need to compile your source code into browser understandable

Comment: I tried running `browserify src/person.js > bundle.js` and creating `index.html` and put `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`. Do i have to do anything else for my `karma start` to work?